# Trouble displaying content in tab Microsoft Teams. in our published app

Tags: json, microsoft-teams

Teams App Submission suggested to regarding query about our bug/problem:

> "Thanks for your email. Regarding your query, request you log your
> feedback here Microsoft Teams developer community help and feedback -
> Teams | Microsoft Docs  they will help you in resolving the issue."

Ok. We're having trouble displaying content in our published app. In tab. Tab is managed from the manifest level (.json). Therefore, we have no real influence on its operation. The app has no control over this. Apart from specifying it in json and adding a link to Microsoft Forms.

Tab w JSON:

```json
{

    "entityId": "Raports",

    "name": "Raports",

    "contentUrl": "https://forms.office.com/e/contoso",

    "websiteUrl": "https://forms.office.com/e/contoso",

    "scopes": [

        "personal"

    ],

    "context": [

        "personalTab"

    ]
}
```

I tried everything :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SycB7.png)

Comment: The same issue is being tracked here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1633937/trouble-displaying-content-in-tab-microsoft-teams. Please follow this thread for further updates. Thank you.

Comment: The question lacks detail, what is actually happening, do you see a blank screen? Does the content display and but look right?

Answer (score 0):

Since there's not much information to go on in your question I'm going to speculate and assume you're seeing no content at all in this tab (please add more info to your question to clarify exactly what you see).

The issue you're having may be around authentication, teams tabs are essentially IFRAMEs within the teams application. If you're linking to a form which requires the user to be logged in most likely the form is being redirected to the Microsoft login page at https://login.microsoft.com and a login page is diplayed which has a "X-Frame-Options: SameOrigin" header which will not display in an IFRAME.

To avoid this you must first log the user in to the tab, establish that they are logged in, and then forward them to your form. This will avoid the login page at https://login.microsoft.com being displayed as the user will already be logged in.

See this link for instructions on setting up tab SSO: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/tab-sso-overview

Comment: Hi @JustAnotherDay we have in Tab Microsoft Forms form ;) Without logining in.